# Trouble writing a csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a script so that the output will be a .csv of 5 columns: 2 of data, followed by an empty column, and then 2 more columns of data. Here is [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYT90.jpg) and here is [what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIz0D.jpg). For completeness, here is all of my code.

```
import requests
import csv

item_dictionary = {'10350': 'Third-Age Full', '560':'Death Rune'}
item_ids = item_dictionary.keys()
url_template = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=%r'

sites = []
for i in range(0, len(item_ids)):
    result = url_template % item_ids[i]
    sites.append(result)


def data_grabber(item): 
    url = item
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
    data = r.json  
    prices = [i[1] for i in data]
    return prices


data = map(data_grabber, sites)

names = item_dictionary.values()

def writer(item):
    q = data.index(item) 
    headers = [names[q], 'Percent Change', None]   
    a = data[q]
    percents = [100.0 * a1 / a2 - 100 for a1, a2 in zip(a[1:], a)]
    percents.insert(0, None)
    f = zip(data[q], percents)
    myfile = open('prices.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(headers)
    wr.writerows(f)
    myfile.close()

z = [writer(x) for x in data]
```

I think that what's happening is that `writer(item)` writes two columns, and the next iteration of `z` overwrites those columns. EDIT: I noticed that I have `myfile.close()` in the function. That would explain it, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You know what a file mode of `'wb'` does, right?

Comment: Not really. I think I took it out of an example somewhere.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if you are writing a very simple CSV such as this, then you don't really need the `csv` package. Just open the file and write away:

```
f = open("out.csv", "w")
...
for line in lines:
    //line = ["col1","col2","","col3",""]
    csv_line = str.join(",",line)
    f.writeline(csv_line)
f.close()
```

If your data is more complex (i.e. not purely numeric) you will run into problems however.

Comment: Right up until you hit something with a comma or quotes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams >"If you are just writing a simple CSV like this"

Answer (score 0):

Open the file only once, then:

```
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
wr.writerow(headers)
for x in data:
    # prepare row data
    # ... (the modified body of writer() function goes here)
    # write it as csv
    wr.writerow(row) # row is a list with 5 items
myfile.close()
```

When you open a file in 'wb' mode its size is truncated to zero and the previous content is lost. So when you call `writer()` function multiple times it replaces all previous content, only rows from the last call are left in the file.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I've been tinkering around for half an hour and still can't get it to work.